# Changing default download location

Tags: android, download, location

Does anybody have an idea about changing the default download location in android? Or do you guys know how can I write an Android application which asks the user download location (sd card or usb memory)?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean downloading from a link in the browser it is up to the browser to set the folder the files are stored in. The default browser uses sdcard/download/ to store files. I am not sure if you can change this in the browser settings or not. But there is nothing stopping you or anyone from making your own browser application that uses a different folder by default, or even asks the user to set their own choice of download folder. I think the firefox app uses sdcard/downloads/ instead of download, they may have a setting in there that lets you change that also.

Comment: I can modify the source code and provide a download dialog where to download. "sdcard/download/" i could not find this in the source code of the browser still searching. thanks for your answer

Comment: it would be great though to store any download on external sdcard by default. may there be some kind of hard linking possibility to map the folder /sdcard/download to /extsdcard/download (e.g. on filesystem layer)?

Comment: @jamesdietriq if i recall, there are API calls in Android that return various default directories, which could be why you don't see the string you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From: 
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/972722

Type about:config (go to this address) and go past the prompt, change the value of browser.download.lastDir to your download location.
Havent tried this yet im using beta app

Answer (score 0):

You can change your save location when using a Samsung Browser by going into Settings > Advanced > Save content to and select SD Card (if you have one)

Comment: The OP never said anything about Samsung browser or phone. Your answer should be generic enough to work on any device.